# Есть 2 ссылки разделенные между собой, надо сделать анимацию при наведение, того что одна ссылка заменяет другую

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
.header__auth {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 184px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F57B3A;
  margin: 5px 0;
  /* orange */
  border: 1px solid #F57B3A;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
.hr {
  height: 100%;
  border: 0.5px solid #F57B3A;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  // color:#F57B3A;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__auth">
  <a class="header__auth-signin">Log In</a>
  <hr />
  <a class="header__auth-signup">Sign Up</a>
</div>
```

Как можно убрать вторую ссылку с плавной анимацией свайпа вправо другой ссылки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно получиться примерно так

Comment: Для самой анимации сдвига можно просто добавить `@keyframes` со смещением положения ссылки. Однако, как я понимаю, вопрос этим не ограничивается, и простая реализация сдвига одной ссылки не даст финального решения задачи. Вероятно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону уже существующих решений данной проблемы в виде CSS-фреймворков.

Comment: Попробуйте описать более подробно как должен происходить _свайп_ другой ссылки и, если это возможно, попытаться графически изобразить как это должно выглядеть в итоге.